# php mail show sometimes symbols

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fetching mysql data and using php @mail like this:

```
$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From:example@example.com\r\n";

    $strHeader .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // or UTF-8 //
    $strHeader .= $strMessage . "\r\n";

    $flgSend = @mail($strTo, $strSubject, null, $strHeader); // @ = No Show Error //
    if ($flgSend) {
        echo "Excel Generated & Email Sending.";
    } else {
        echo "Email Can Not Send.";
    }
```

now i'm getting sometimes the symbol � , all the data is shown correct just someimes it turn one letter in one word to �.

must to say when i'm changing the

```
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: text/html
```

to

$strHeader .= "Content-Type: text/plain

there is no incorrect symbols.

any idea? 
thanks,
Mor

Comment: the message is being sent with utf-8 as the character encoding and I guess some of the data within $strMessage has characters that cannot be represented with utf-8. You could try using iconv to convert the data first

Comment: I don't understand why it happen. because sometimes it can show this specific letter and only one time in one practicullar word it show this symbol.  also when i'm printing the $strmessage with echo it looks fine. just when i'm using the php @mail it appear inccorect in my email.   i tried to use iconv but it looks worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it.
in PHP mail In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
example:

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";


$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use mb_encode_mimeheader(), check,

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php
```

Comment: Hi @chandu thanks for reply. but it's the same. i need to show "hebrew" letters so actually i need utf-8